# How to add dependencies of thymeleaf with Play framework 1.4.1

Tags: playframework, thymeleaf, playframework-1.x

How to add dependencies of thymeleaf with Play framework 1.4.1

I have done like below but it is not working ....

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Puneet Mathur">

    <!-- core CSS -->
    <link href="../../public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"  th:href="@{'/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css'}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../public/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{'/public/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css'}" rel="stylesheet">
```

...
I have also tried `th:src="@{/public/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.js}"` but it is not working